# Devexpress: An object reference is required for the non-static field

Tags: wpf, devexpress, xtrareport

I keep getting this error in my devexpress code.
Here is the code I have put in:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using DevExpress.XtraReports.UI;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

namespace DD
{
    public partial class MasterReport : DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport
    {
        //detailReport.catName.Value = ((DataRowView)e.Brick.Value).Row["EcoYear"].ToString();
        public MasterReport()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void xrLabel1_BeforePrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
        {
         //   XRLabel l = sender as XRLabel;
         //   l.Tag = GetCurrentRow();

           ((XRLabel)sender).Tag = GetCurrentRow();
        }

        private void xrLabel1_PreviewClick(object sender, PreviewMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            DetailReport detailReport = new DetailReport();
            detailReport.CaID.Value = (int)((DataRowView)e.Brick.Value).Row["CaseID"];
            detailReport.EYear.Value = (int)((DataRowView)e.Brick.Value).Row["EcoYear"];
            detailReport.ShowPreviewDialog();
        }

        private void xrLabel1_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, PreviewMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand;
        }

        private void xrPictureBox1_BeforePrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
        {
            ((XRLabel)sender).Tag = GetCurrentRow();
        }

        private void xrPictureBox1_PreviewClick(object sender, PreviewMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            PW pw = new PW();
            PW.CaID.Value = (int)((DataRowView)e.Brick.Value).Row["CaseCaseID"];
            PW.ShowPreviewDialog();
        }

        private void xrPictureBox1_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, PreviewMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand;
        }

    }
}
```

The PW.CaID.Value and the PW.ShowPreviewDialog(); are the lines that are giving me this error. Perhaps I am doing this the wrong way. What I wanted to do is click an icon (xrPictureBox1) on the main report and have it bring up the subreport (PW). I have done this in the code above for another subreport (detailreport). Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should read:

```
PW pw = new PW();
pw.CaID.Value = (int)((DataRowView)e.Brick.Value).Row["CaseCaseID"];
pw.ShowPreviewDialog();
```

Note the case on PW/pw.